# What's this in R operator: %||%?

Tags: r

Encountered in tidyverse function (googledrive::drive_upload) as in:

```
dots <- toCamel(list(...))
dots$fields <- dots$fields %||% "*"
```

Because of the nature of the term, hard to search documentation for it. How should I have searched?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `help("%||%")` or `?"%||%"` should work if you have the package that provides it loaded. `getAnywhere` can help you find what package it is a part of, or the `sos` package searches many packages.